# Trying to only return results for multiple must matches - elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Consider this PHP array for defining a search query on elasticsearch

```
    $searchParams = [
        'index' => $index_name,
        'type' => 'nginx-access',
        'size' => 1000,
        'sort' => ['_score'],
        'fields' => ["remote_addr", "@timestamp", "request", "method", "status"],
        'body' => [
            // 'min_score' => 4,
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        ['match' => ['status' => '200']],
                        ['match' => ['method' => 'POST']],
                        ['match' => ['request' => '/wp-login.php']],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $results = $this->client->search($searchParams);
    var_dump($results);
```

Notice that 'min_score' is commented out. The array of results returns everything as expected, however I *only* want results that match all of the criteria. I thought this is what query->bool->must is supposed to do, however near the end of the dataset I am getting matches for other seemingly random things as well.

If I run it with min_score then I'm always going to get the results I want, but this does not seem the right way to do it.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Yeah, probably your query is matching the correct things but you don't know that what is matching is also correct. What's the mapping of fields `status`, `method` and `request`? Give some sample documents that you thing **they shouldn't match**.